# Join current_user's rate to each song

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rabl, sqlperformance

I need to show current user's rate of the song in index.

I have associated models:

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy

  def user_rate(user)
    votes.find_by(user_id: user).try(:rate)
  end
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :song, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :user
end
```

votes table:

```
  create_table "votes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "rate"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "song_id
  end
```

And index action in SongsController:

```
def index
  respond_with @songs = Song.includes(:votes).all
end
```

In songs/index.json.rabl I look for current user vote (each user can vote only once)

```
collection @songs
extends "songs/base"
attributes :thumb_cover
node(:current_user_rate){ |song| song.user_rate(current_user) }
```

but the `song.user_rate(current_user)` generates **n+1** queries :(

```
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Song Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "songs".* FROM "songs"
  Vote Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "votes".* FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."song_id" = ? AND "votes"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1  [["song_id", 1]]
  Vote Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "votes".* FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."song_id" = ? AND "votes"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1  [["song_id", 2]]
```

Is there a way I can joins current user's vote.rate column to each song in one query?

Comment: `votes.find_by(user_id: user).try(:rate)` did you mean Vote.find_by?

Comment: and you are querrying all votes by user, not specific to the song

Comment: That's why I do this by the instance method. When I call Song.first.votes it generates:
`SELECT  "songs".* FROM "songs"  ORDER BY "songs"."id" ASC LIMIT 1`
`SELECT "votes".* FROM "votes" WHERE "votes"."song_id" = ?  [["song_id", 1]]`
and this is ok :)

Comment: yes. and you are calling song.user_rate which is fine. but in user_rate method you are not doing `self.votes.find..` where self would replace `Song.first`. see my answer.

Comment: ok, I've changed to `self.votes.find_by(user_id: user).try(:rate)` in `def user_rate` but it nothing has changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be best diving into [`ActiveRecord Association Extensions`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#association-extensions):

```
#app/models/song.rb
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy do
     def user_rate(user)
       find_by(user_id: user.id).try(:rate)
     end
  end
end
```

This would allow:

```
@song   = Song.find params[:id]
@rating = @song.votes.user_rate current_user #-> 5 or false
```

---

If you didn't want to perform another query, you could try your hand at the `proxy_association` object which is accessible through the extension:

```
#app/models/song.rb
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy do
     def user_rate(user)
       ratings = proxy_association.target.map {|f| [f.user_id, f.rate]}
       rating = ratings.select { |user_id, rate| user_id == user.id }
       rating.first[1] if rating.first
     end
  end
end
```

You'll be able to use:

```
@song   = Song.find params[:id]
@rating = @song.votes.try(:by, current_user) #-> 5 or false

if @rating
 ...
end
```

Untested, but I've used `proxy_association` before in similar ways to this.

Comment: Great! :D I had to make some changes (I've edited your answer), but it's working like a charm! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

change to;

```
def self.user_rate(user)
  self.votes.find_by(user_id: user.id).try(:rate)
end
```

Comment: So wait, `rate` is a field in `Vote`?

Comment: the above method will return the rating of the user for the song. Is that not happening?

Comment: Yes, eg @song has 2 votes: {id: 1, rate: 2, user_id: 1, song_id: 1} and {id: 2, rate: 5, user_id: 2, song_id: 1}, so @song.user_rate(User.first) will eq 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101948/discussion-between-haider-and-szymon-rut).